# Can we get received date of a deleted item while using delta query in JAVA SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

For a message deleted is it possible to get the received date using delta query. Right now, we only get **ID** and **@removed : {"reason" : "deleted"}.** If we try to get the message using its id, we can't find it since it doesn't exist in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the service today. You can upvote the [following idea in uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/20440105-get-deleted-events) to help prioritize the ask.